# Java switch statement asking for input twice

Tags: java, loops, input, switch-statement

I don't understand what is going on with this switch statement. I'm trying to have the user input l for less and m for more. If they put less then it would do the calculations under the 'l' case only. But this seems to be asking the user for input from the 'l' case AND going to the 'm' case and asking again so the user has to input l l for less and m m for more instead of just once.

Is this a problem with trying to use switch or a problem with the way I wrote the code?

```
        while (choice == console.next().charAt(0));

EDIT: Figured out this was asking for input instead so it kept asking twice each time.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for choice twice, once in the case statements:

```
        case 'l':   //If it is lower then 499 becomes the upperBound
            upperBound = nextGuess;
            tries++;
            nextGuess = ( (lowerBound + upperBound)/2 );
            System.out.println("Is it " + nextGuess + 
                 "? \n\t Enter y if it is, l if it is less, or m if it is more.");

            // **** here ****
            choice = console.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.println("LOWER");
            break;
```

and again in the while condition, i.e.,

```
    while (choice == console.next().charAt(0));
```

Solution: Get the input only **once**.

Comment: Ok I thought that meant it would keep running while it was taking in the input for choice but It is actually taking in the input again. Thank you I was able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are asking for choice twice (inside case and in while condition).
2. Rethink this while condition once again:

   ```
   while (choice == console.next().charAt(0))
   ```

Its not just asking for input one more time. It also breaks the loop when user changes her/his mind...

You should remove console reading from while condition and change it to something like:

```
while(choice != 'y');
```

Comment: Yea that is exactly what I did to fix it. At the time I thought I was setting the condition to be "do this while it ask for this input" in a literal sense.